# Is matrix picture of quantum mechnics further used in QFT and superstring theories?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, string-theory

Just curious: is matrix picture of quantum mechnaics further used in QFT and superstring theories? It seems like not....

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38070/2451

Comment: Is not matrix theory the ultimate generalization of the matrix picture of quantum mechanics as described for example [here](http://motls.blogspot.com/2012/05/matrix-theory-novel-alternative-to.html) and [here](http://www.motls.blogspot.com/2012/06/why-matrix-theory-contains-membranes.html) ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "matrix mechanics" – known as "operator formalism" or "Heisenberg picture of quantum mechanics" – is used in all quantum mechanical theories. QFTs and string theory aren't exceptions. In all these cases, all the matrices are infinitely large, of course, because the Hilbert space is infinite-dimensional. However, that was true already for the quantum mechanics describing one particle on a line – for the simplest quantum mechanical models with at least one continuous degree of freedom. So QFT and string theory change nothing conceptual about these matters.